# Arranging size of a frame in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a simple toolbox for my app. I have used the class method, which inherits `Frame` as its super class. In my main file I import this class.

It will be a main window which all widgets will be in it. But there is a problem, here is the source code:

```
from tkinter import *

class ToolBox(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None,
                 width=100, height=300):
        Frame.__init__(self, master,
                       width=100, height=300)
        self.pack()
        Button(self, text="B").grid(row=0, sticky=(N,E,W,S))
        Button(self, text="B").grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=(N,E,W,S))
        Button(self, text="B").grid(row=1, column=0,sticky=(N,E,W,S))
        Button(self, text="B").grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=(N,E,W,S))
        Button(self, text="B").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=(N,E,W,S))
        Button(self, text="B").grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=(N,E,W,S))
```

I import this in here:

```
from tkinter import *
import toolbox as tl

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root, width=400, height=400)
frame.pack()
tl.ToolBox(frame).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Main window, which is the `root` who has the `frame`, must be 400 in widht and height. But it appears in dimensions of my toolbox. I want the toolbox to be in the main window. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the root window to have specific dimensions using the `geometry` method.

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
```

If you would also like the buttons to stretch evenly to fill the whole root window, you need to do two things:

1. Call `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure` to set the weight of the root and each frame that is a parent of your buttons.
2. specify the sticky parameter for every button and frame that is a child of your root.

Here's an example. I removed your `frame` Frame, since it didn't seem to be doing anything. Toolbox is already a frame, after all, and there's not much point putting a frame inside a frame.

```
from tkinter import *

class ToolBox(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None,
                 width=100, height=300):
        Frame.__init__(self, master,
                       width=width, height=height)
        for i in range(2):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
        for j in range(3):
            self.grid_rowconfigure(j, weight=1)

        Button(self, text="B").grid(row=0, sticky=(N,E,W,S))
        Button(self, text="B").grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=(N,E,W,S))
        Button(self, text="B").grid(row=1, column=0,sticky=(N,E,W,S))
        Button(self, text="B").grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=(N,E,W,S))
        Button(self, text="B").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=(N,E,W,S))
        Button(self, text="B").grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=(N,E,W,S))

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

ToolBox(root).grid(sticky="news")

root.mainloop()
```

Now your root is properly sized, and your buttons stretch to fill it.

[image]